Is Lord Śiva's throat Really Blue?
We all are aware of the fact that Lord Rudra ( Śiva ) drank the Kālakūṭa poison which came out of the ocean during the Samudra Manthana and his throat became blue.
But did it really become blue?
In the Vayu Purāṇa(one of the oldest Purāṇas) we see that -
पिबतो मे महाघोरं विषं सुरभयंकरम् ॥ कण्ठः समभवत्तूर्णं कृष्णो मे वरणिनि
Here , it is told that after drinking the poison , Mahādeva's throat turned into Kṛṣṇa Varṇa which is Black colour.
Also , in the Mārgabandhu Stotram by Śrī Appayya Dīkṣita , the 4th Śloka  reads -
kandarpadarpaghnamīśaṃ kālakaṇṭhaṃ maheśaṃ mahāvyomakeśam .    kundābhadantaṃ sureśaṃ koṭisūryaprakāśaṃ bhaje mārgabandhum .                           
Here , the world Kālakaṇṭha is used for Lord Śiva , which means Black-Throated.
As we also find the Epithet Nīlagrīva for Rudra in the Vedas , Does Nīla Also mean Dark or Black?
Please answer.
Namaha Śivāya


Poetic freedom allows them to imagine the shades from darkest blue to black. Even Sri Vishnu is called NikameghaShama. (Blue clouds)

Thanks but my main concern is actually with the meaning of the word "Nīla" , even in the Chhāndogya Upaniṣad , Nīla is equated with black. In texts like Chhāndogya Upaniṣad , there's no question of "Poetic Freedom" as they are Śruti. Can you tell me about the real meaning of the word "Nīla" , I've asked this again and again on this platform but I've got everything but a satisfactory answer with references from Scriptures. And what about the reference that I gave  from Vāyu Purāṇa  @SanatanaDhara

all Vedic literature is metered in a poetic construct for mnemonics, it may not be the romantic imaginative poetry style. But Nila when attributed to color is Blue or Dark Blue. Here is an article that describes various colors and its relations to Rudra in Vedas, hope this will help what you are looking for. https://namahshivaya.net/appearance-of-rudra-visvarupam/

@SanatanaDhara thanks! Is the tale of Rudra destroying the Yajña in which he was not invited present in any other recension of the Yajurveda? We know that this tale is present in the Taittirīya Samhitā 2.6.8 , in the Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa 1.7.3 and also in the Uttara Bhāga of the Gopatha Brāhmaṇa. But is it found in any other recension of the Kṛṣna Yajurveda (like maitrayani , Katha and Kapishtala ).

its a slight misunderstanding that arises from reading Puranas first and then the Vedic Brahmanas. its not that Rudra come to destroy Yajña, its more of Rudra emerging as an aftermath. And its not just in one vedic śākhā. The aftermath of an Yajña can be because of:

wrong chant, 2. Pāpa (consume negative outcome) like Prajapat's Yajña, 3. Omission or overlooking some thing or Rudra himself gets overlooked,
So there are many exploits between Prajapati and Rudra. Here is a link that shows why and many Vedic references https://namahshivaya.net/rudra-the-vedic-enforcer-punisher/


Thanks! I know it's a common mistake to study the Purāṇas before The Vedic Brāhmaṇa Passages. I just wanted to know if the Brāhmaṇa Passage of TS 2.6.8 and ŚB 1.7.3 is also mentioned in other Kṛṣna Yajurveda Śākhas , like the description of Tripura-Samhāra by Rudra is found in every surving Śākhā of the Kṛṣna Yajurveda with minor and major variations. So please tell me if the "Brāhmaṇa Passage" of Rudra piercing the Yajña is present in other Kṛṣna Yajurveda Samhitās too. @SanatanaDhara
